# Has anyone ever tried to use DialerFilter?

Tags: android, android-widget

DialerFilter, located in Android.widget has almost zero documentation. Has anyone tried to use it / knows what it does?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it converts letters to text according to old-fashioned phone keyboards (abc=2, def=3, etc)